# What methods should I use from PythonCyc API to query metabolites in BioCyc database?

Tags: python, api

I am using **PythonCyc** API in order to write a query for metabolites in **BioCyc**. The purpose of this API is to communicate with the database software of BioCyc- Pathway Tools. Pathway Tools is in lisp therefore, PythonCyc creates a bridge between python and common lisp. To use this this API one must first create a PGDB object with a specified organism ID (orgid). In the example below I create a PGDB with orgid "meta". After this, I am able to call methods from PythonCyc with this object:

```
import sys
import pythoncyc
#this creates PGDB object associated with meta(MetaCyc)
meta = pythoncyc.select_organism('meta')
#lists pathways of specified compound
pathways = meta.pathways_of_compound('sucrose')
print pathways
```

The query for the metabolite above, 'sucrose', provides a list a pathways:

```
[u'|PWY-7347|', u'|SUCSYN-PWY|', u'|PWY-7238|', u'|PWY-6527|', u'|PWY-5343|', u'|PWY-3801|', u'|PWY-7345|', u'|PWY-862|', u'|SUCUTIL-PWY|', u'|PWY66-373|', u'|PWY-621|', u'|PWY-822|', u'|SUCROSEUTIL2-PWY|', u'|PWY-6525|', u'|PWY-6524|', u'|PWY-5337|', u'|PWY-5384|']
```

However if I switch this metabolite name to a common amino acid name, such as 'valine':

```
import sys
import pythoncyc
#this creates PGDB object associated with meta(MetaCyc)
meta = pythoncyc.select_organism('meta')
#lists pathways of specified compound
pathways = meta.pathways_of_compound('valine')
print pathways
```

The query provides an error message that states "non coercible frame", which means it cannot find this ID. This is a common metabolite, just as sucrose, which should very well have pathway entries in database, however there are none found with this method. I have also tried synonyms of valine and other methods such as "all_pathways(cpds)" stated in API, which give me the same error message.
What is the reason for this? Does BioCyc not list any pathways for amino acids? Or am I using an incorrect method to access amino acid information?

[Link to PythonCyc API](http://pythoncyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Hi astrika, thanks for your question and welcome to Bioinformatics Stack Exchange. I've had a glance over this question, and it looks like it has the potential to get good answers: it is well-researched, with a good story, and a specific question. I look forward to seeing more questions from you in the future.

Answer (score 3):

**UPD**: As [suggested](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/623/what-methods-should-i-use-from-pythoncyc-api-to-query-metabolites-in-biocyc-data/651?noredirect=1#comment3035_651) by Llopis, maybe the correct identifier is VAL?

I think there is no metabolite with such name in the database. I tried [their search](https://biocyc.org/ECOLI/search-query?type=COMPOUND&name=Valine), the correct name seems to be `L-valine`. I expect that they use similar naming for other amino acids. If you cannot find something, you can use their compound search through the website.

Comment: I have tried 'L-valine' in the script above and it has also gave me the same error. I am aware it is possible to search in the site, however for my purpose I must write a query. My purpose is to obtain possible pathway networks for a given metabolics dataset

Comment: @astrika maybe the name is [Protein-L-valine](https://biocyc.org/compound?orgid=ECOLI&id=Protein-L-valine), or [VAL](https://biocyc.org/compound?orgid=ECOLI&id=VAL). One thing is how they store things an another is how they show them. Sorry I didn't test how to search using python

Answer (score 3):

Pathway-tools has a unique identifier (called a Frame-ID) for each metabolite in its database.  You can get the list of all compounds with this api call:

`all_cpds = meta.get_class_all_instances('|Compounds|')`

for each compound, you can also get its common name, or all its synonyms:

`cpd_names = {}
for cpd_frame_id in all_cpds:
      cpd_names[cpd_frame_id] = meta.get_name_string(cpd_frame_id)`